# Is there a recommended ami-ec2 image for dse 4.7.2 which includes spark and mllib

Tags: datastax

i would like to install datastax 4.7.2 or the latest version on ec2 and take advantage of spark and mllib. Is there a recommended image that I can use to ssh into?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataStax AMI](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMIlaunch.html). DSE is free in Dev or in Prod for [qualifying startups](http://www.datastax.com/datastax-enterprise-for-startups).

Just get your credentials by filling out the [download form](http://www.datastax.com/download).

Comment: I tried one of the images that per instructions provided but am unable to start cassandra

Comment: No cluster configurations set. Using the default options:
--totalnodes 1 --version Community --clustername "Test Cluster - No AMI Parameters"



[ERROR] 08/09/15-05:30:24 nodetool -h localhost ring:
nodetool: Failed to connect to 'localhost:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.
[ERROR] 08/09/15-05:54:42 sudo mount -a:
[ERROR] 08/09/15-05:55:47 nodetool -h localhost ring:
nodetool: Failed to connect to 'localhost:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.

Comment: [EXEC] 08/09/15-06:11:44 sudo service datastax-agent restart:
 * Restarting DataStax Agent datastax-agent
   ...done.

[ERROR] 08/09/15-06:12:06 nodetool -h localhost ring:
nodetool: Failed to connect to 'localhost:7199' - ConnectException: 'Conn
ection refused'.

[INFO] Skipping initial configurations.

Comment: Please read section 5 in the docs on Configure Instance Details. What did you have in the user data text box?

Comment: I was trying to ssh into the recommended ec2 instance when it hung  that is no system prompt .
  I had allowed all incoming ports in my security configurations for the purposes of setting this up.
  Is using opcenter my only option to start datastax 4.7 on ec2?

Comment: No, you can use the ami or a tarball, or a package install. In a scenario like the one above, just terminate and try again.

Comment: I did several times and it still hangs

Comment: I have tried all of the recommended ami but with same results.  Is there a way around the auto cluster ami's? We just need a simple setup ie one node so we can gun spark and mllib

Comment: Just spin up an ubuntu node in AWS and install using the debian repo http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html

Comment: also, --version Community  will not install DSE. You won't get Spark integration out of the box with the open source version.

Comment: i think you are wrong in stating "you must be be doing something wrong it works for everyone else ".  I have seen other people have similar problems. However I will try spinning up Ubuntu and installing it separately.

Comment: email me at sebastian.estevez at datastax dot com I'll help you get up and running.